# Batch file to move specific file types into a sub folder

Tags: batch-file, move

I've been wondering about speeding up certain tasks in the office, specifically moving certain file-types to a backup folder. I get the files to move to said folder but it also moves files from every sub-folder. I've tried removing the /R from the command but then it wont run.

```
@echo off
FOR /R "%CD%" %%i IN (*00??.rfa) DO MOVE "%%i" "%CD%\Revit Backups"
FOR /R "%CD%" %%i IN (*00??.rvt) DO MOVE "%%i" "%CD%\Revit Backups"
FOR /R "%CD%" %%i IN (*00??.rte) DO MOVE "%%i" "%CD%\Revit Backups"
echo "The move was super effective!"
pause
```

Comment: *"It won't run"* is not a particularly precise failure description. Open a command prompt window and run the batch script from there rather than just double-clicking on its icon; then you should be able to read any error messages...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a `For /F` loop, passing your searchmasks to the `Where` command:

```batch-file
@For /F %%G In ('%__AppDir__%where.exe /F .:*00??.rfa .:*00??.rvt .:*00??.rte 2^>NUL') Do @Move /Y %%G "Revit Backups" >NUL
```